# discrepancy between app downloaded from play store and installed from android studio

Tags: android, google-play, android-image

Ok, hi.

I have an app that uses some JPG nad PNG images, the images are dispalyed fine if i install the app from android studio, but when i download it and install it from play store, the images are shown just as a black square.

First i thought it was due to having all the images stored in the folder mdpi and i uploaded an aab file to the play store so, i assumed that the problem was that i had to copy the files to all the drawable folders: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi and in the general drawable folder, but the problem persisted.

Then i created an apk file and installed it directly in my smartphone and the problem was there so i suppose that the problem is not related with the google play console nor with the aab format.

i have other images in that folder that are displayed well.
The images are not corrupted, they work fine if i install the app from android studio.

I don't know what files could be useful to help but i will leave the manifest and the build.gradle of the module level:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapppackage">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="com.the.name.of.application"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStyle">
        <activity android:name="com.the.name.of.the.activity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.2.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'
}
```

------------------THIS IS AN EDIT TO TALK ABOUT THE SOLUTION OF THE PROBLEM-------------
Turns out that my problem was with the proguard rules, by some reason android decided that i wasn't using 90% of my images and files stored in the raw folder and kept them out of the project. Due to the process to shrink code and resources been applied only in releases versions the project worked fine when i build it and run it from android studio, but with problems when an apk or aab was generated and install it.

Maybe my images were left out of the project because i don't access them directly, i have their names in a JSON file stored in the raw resources, then i read the file to get the names.

The solution was just setting the
`minifyEnabled false`
`shrinkResources false` properties.

There are other solutions like write new proguard rules or adding an xml file with the tag  but this one is faster

Answer (score 1):

Add these permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then in your activity you must grant this permissions to your app like this

```
private static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private static String[] STORAGE_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};


 /* do the app has permission to write to device storage?
 *
 * if not then the user will be asked to grant permissions
 *
 */
public static void getStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                STORAGE_PERMISSIONS,
                EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST
        );
    }
}
```

You should then do something if the permission is granted

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the results are always empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted Do the
                // image displaying things you want to do.

            } else {

               // permission denied. if there is other option to continue 
               //without permission do it here or finish the activity and ask 
                //for permission in another run. maybe it was a misclick yay?
                 
            }
            return;
        }

       
    }
}
```